# sed, getting an error: sed -e expression #1, char 28: unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed

When I do:

```
sed 's/@driver.quit/#@driver.quit' set_QA_district_name_spec.rb
```

I get the error shown in the title.

How can I get around this error, what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substitute expression was missing the end slash, e.g.

```
sed 's/@driver.quit/#@driver.quit' set_QA_district_name_spec.rb
```

should be

```
sed 's/@driver\.quit/#@driver.quit/' set_QA_district_name_spec.rb
```

Once it worked I added the `-i` ('in-place') flag so the file itself was actually replaced, e.g.

```
sed -i 's/@driver\.quit/#@driver.quit/' set_QA_district_name_spec.rb
```